# Fixed points of contractions in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems, complete-spaces

> How do I prove that all contractions on a complete, non-empty metric space has exactly one fixed point?

**What I know:**
I know that all contractions are continuous and that completeness of $A$  means that all Cauchy sequences converge in $A$, but what can I do with these facts? And I think I also have to prove having two fixed points implies they are the same point to prove uniqueness. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

1. find $d(a_m,a_n)$ with $m>n$ and use the fact the series $1+k+k^2...$ is convergent hence the tail goes to $0$
2. now if it has $2$ fixed points say $x,y$ find  relation between $d(x,y)$ and $d(f(x),f(y))$ where $f$ is the contraction

Comment: 2. If $d(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$ does that imply $x=y$?

Comment: can you explain how is the implication coming this way?

Comment: No, since I don't know why

Comment: Could you maybe expand a bit more on your hints?

Comment: well, what is the definition of contraction? $d(f(x),f(y))<c.d(x,y)$ for some $0<c<1$ now deduce that $d(x,y)=0$

Comment: But if that is true, then $d(f(x),f(y))$ would be negative. Also how do I prove that there exists a fixed point at all?